# css media query not working on 400px width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Trying to copy some front end mentor challenges. I'm almost done with my work. the problem is when I tried to give media query for 400px responsive styling doesnt works.I want to hide right element for max width 400px.but the media query doesnt work.in my laptop when i resize my browser the right section doesnt hide according to the width of window.but at the same time if i give @media screen and (max-width: 500px)media query as 500px it works fine.Kindly help me this issue.also i want to display the image fit to the screen in 400px.there is margin on both left&right side.how to remove that make it full screen in mobile.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,700&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400;600&family=Montserrat:wght@500;700&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url('/images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg');
}


.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    
}

.container .left{
    width: 60%;
    padding: 60px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.container .right{
    width: 40%;
    background-image: url('/images/hero-desktop.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.left h1{
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5rem;
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    font-weight: 200;

}

.left h1 span{
    color: black;
}

.left p{
    color: hsl(0, 36%, 70%);
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.inputgrp{
    position: relative;
}

.left button{

    background-image:  linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
     left: -101px;
     top: 1px;
    
}

.left input{

    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 36%, 70%) ;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
    padding-right: 113px;
     width: 60%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    
}

.container .bgmobile{
    display: none;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    
    .right{
        display: none;
    }

    .left{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container .bgmobile{
        display: block;
        margin-left: -40px;
        margin-right: -40px;
        width: calc(100%+80px);
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Base Apparel coming soon page</title>

  
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <header>
        <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
      </header>
      <img src="/images/hero-mobile.jpg" alt="" class="bgmobile">
      <h1> We're <br><span>coming<br> soon</span></h1>
      <p>Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new <br>
        fashion store. Add your email below to stay up-to-date with<br> 
        announcements and our launch deals.</p>

        <form action="#">
          <div class="inputgrp">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
          <img src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="" class="error">
          <button type="submit"><img src="/images/icon-arrow.svg " ></button>
        
          <div class="errormsg">
            <small>please provide a valid Email</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <img src="">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*the media query doesnt work*" - in what way? Giving `.right` a `background-color: lime` it certain seems to disappear as you wish: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k0mg6a9f/

Comment: Hello there. Please explain your question better. Hard to understand. This said however, when I tried your code, it works fine, the "right" section you want to hide, does hide. I saw no issue with it.

Comment: in my laptop when i resize my browser the right section doesnt hide according to the width  of window.but at the same time if i give @media screen and (max-width: 500px)media query as 500px it works.my basic problem is it is not working at 400px.i have to give 500px as max width

Comment: The problem is that it works for us, so it looks like you're going to have to investigate what's happening on your own machine; does the JS Fiddle I linked to work for you?

Comment: ohh well lol. yeah depending on HOW you are resizing your browser, it may/may not work. your media query makes a change at 400px, but if you resize the browser manually the smallest it'll go is around 454. Open up your browser dev tools(or right click on an empty area and click "inspect", and then grab the brim of the browser and make it as small as po ssible, you will see the smallest size on top right of window. You will see the smallest it gets is to around 450 or so, which doesn't meet your sizing. Thats why you may see it "not working". Its cause its not meeting media q. sizing.

Comment: Instead of just resizing your browser have you tried you browsers dev tools inspect facility and chosen some of the narrower devices to emulate?